# Photoshop zoomed in "frame"

Tags: reference, panel, frame, photoshop

I'm new to photoshop. I want to make a "frame" (think a comic panel) with a zoomed-in view on the part of the image. Any changes to the layers should be reflected in it. And that frame should be visible in the finished render.
Ideally I want to be able to rotate and distort that view.

Basically I want a monitor on the foreground that shows a zoom in on the part of the image. And i want that monitor to automatically reflect any changes.

Just to be clear, i don't need Droste effect where the screen shows itself recursively. I just need it once.

Just copy and resize method doesnt work for me because the image is interactive with many layers/variants, and I don't want to resize and crop 200 times.

Is that possible? What tools do I use?

Thank you!

Comment: You may be able to achieve this with smart layers. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to ask this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two very different questions here.

**Reflect your changes in another layer**

1. Convert the layergroup into a SmartObject
2. Copy the SmartObject
3. Add a Layermask to the SmartObject Copy
4. Fill the Layermask with Black
5. Paint with a White Brush where the SmartObject Copy must be vissible
6. Unlink the mask from the SmartObject Copy
7. Click the SmartObject Copy
8. Transform the SmartObject Copy

To edit the SmartObject simply

1. Dobbeltclick the SmartObject
2. Make edits
3. Save and close the SmartObject

I have made a short video (3 min) to show you how:
https://youtu.be/9yO4rG3Q16w

**Reflect your changes on a second monitor with a different view on the file**

If you want to work on the image on one monitor and show the image in a different size on an other monitor then use this Photoshop funktion:
Window > Arrange > New Window for [filename]
This will give you a second view on the same file and every change you make on one view is imidiately reflected in the other view. Drag that second view to the other monitor, zoom, move and voila!